# Problema com url

Tags: php, jquery

Fiz uma página em que todo o conteúdo está nela (não tem outras páginas).
Tive que adaptar uma espécie de url amigável nela, pois, ao clicar nas seções da página, o cursor vai até o determinado ponto.
Está funcionando corretamente, mas fica um # na url.

```js
$("a.menu__item").on('click', function(event) {

  if (this.hash !== "") {

    event.preventDefault();

    var hash = this.hash;

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, function() {

      window.location.hash = hash;

    });
  }
});
```

Eu consegui tirar o #

```js
$("a.menu__item").on('click', function(event) {

  if (this.hash !== "") {

    event.preventDefault();

    var hash = this.hash;

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, function() {

      history.pushState(null, null, 'a.menu__item');
      if (history.pushState) {
        var url_a = hash.substring(1, hash.length);
        history.pushState(null, null, url_a);
      } else {
        location.hash = url_a;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Porém, seu eu abrir a página em cliente/blog, diz que a página não existe.
Seria melhor deixar o # ou é plausível alguma ideia para o problema de abrir a página e ela não existir?

Comment: Amigo o # é pra especificar que o que você está procurando está dentro da própria página html, se você tirar o # o navegador irá procurar um arquivo com esse nome e consequentemente irá retornar 404(not found) se você fez tudo dentro da sua página o ideal é deixar o # na url.

Comment: Entendi. Precisava de mais alguma ideia. Vou deixar então. Muito obrigado.